# git fetch bundle - not a repository

Tags: git, bundle

I have a git repository with the following commits history

```
f3b3eca fileone
```

and the same repo in another place, a little updated, with the following history:

```
7d3e66e trzecia zmiana
7e3e171 druga zmiana
f3b3eca fileone
```

I want to create bundle including two commits from the newer repo and to apply it to the first repo (if I had a connection to remote repository it would just be 'git pull')

I create a bundle in the second repository:

```
git bundle create mybundle -2 master
```

I verify it:

```
$ git bundle verify mybundle
The bundle contains this ref:
7d3e66edbac4ea77cb5d9956fcf44b4761a2f1db refs/heads/master
The bundle requires this ref:
f3b3eca59005cea576795f68f6e378616df4bd23
bundletestproj//mybundle is okay
```

However when I try to apply it to the first repository:

```
git fetch mybundle
```

the error occures:

```
fatal: 'mybundle' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The same happens when I try to fetch the bundle created from the whole repository like this (git clone works for this one):

```
git bundle create repo.bundle HEAD master
```

Should I do bundling in some other way? What is the reason of git's such behaviour? I followed the documentation in all these steps.

Comment: `git bundle create mybundle -2 master` creates a file named `mybundle`. How do you transfer that file to import it into the other repo? Where is it in the file system? Did you copy it directly into the 2nd repo directory?

Comment: Yes, I copy the file to another directory in my computer. This just for proof-of-concept purpose. The real life case is such that I have no VPN access to the repo, and my colleague does and I can send him a bundle via email for example. I am 100% sure that the bundle file exist in the repository in which I want to apply it.

Comment: I wonder if `git fetch` is interpreting `mybundle` as a remote name instead of a file name.

Comment: Try `git fetch ../path/to/mybundle`